# Scrollable Canvas with movable items inside ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, windows-phone-8

I've got a ScrollViewer which contains Canvas. There are some movable UIElements at this Canvas. Here is my XAML code:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="White">
       <Canvas x:Name="MapCanvas" Width="4000" Height="4000">    
                    <Button x:Name="TestBtn" 
                            Content="My button"
                            Canvas.Left="250"
                            ManipulationStarted="MapItem_ManipulationStarted"   
                            ManipulationDelta="MapItem_ManipulationDelta" 
                            ManipulationCompleted="MapItem_ManipulationCompleted"   
                            />                                  
      </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Here is the code of event handlers:

```
private void MapItem_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement btn = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (null == btn) return;            

            double left = Canvas.GetLeft(btn) + e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
            double top = Canvas.GetTop(btn) + e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;

            if (left < 0)
                left = 0;
            else if (left >  MapCanvas.ActualWidth - btn.ActualWidth)
                left = MapCanvas.ActualWidth - btn.ActualWidth;

            if (top < 0)
                top = 0;
            else if(top > MapCanvas.ActualHeight - btn.ActualHeight)
                top = MapCanvas.ActualHeight - btn.ActualHeight;

            Canvas.SetLeft(btn, left);
            Canvas.SetTop(btn, top);

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void MapItem_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Scroller.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
            Scroller.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;            

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void MapItem_ManipulationStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            Scroller.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
            Scroller.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;

            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Everything works perfect. But when ScrollViewer has scrolled to some HorizontalOffset or VerticalOffset  and I'm clicking or tapping any UIElement in visible area it seems like ScrollViewer automatically scrolls to HorisontalOffset == 0 and VerticalOffset == 0. Then, after releasing  UIElement, it jumps back.
How can I avoid this behavior and make ScrollViewer stay at it's place while I'll dragging UIElement placed into Canvas inside it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you could try replacing (or adding to) your calls to disable/re-enable the scrollbar visibility with calls to disable/re-enable the `ScrollViewer` control itself:

```
private void MapItem_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    Scroller.IsEnabled = false;
}

private void MapItem_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Scroller.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

If it does work, it may affect the `Style` when it becomes disabled, so you may have to re-style it using a `Trigger` on the `IsEnabled` property when it equals `False`.

Comment: The problem is when ScrollViewer becomes disabled all elements inside it also becomes disabled. So I can't move them too :(

Comment: I realise that this might not be the correct path to take, but if you extend the `Canvas` control, you can add a callback handler to be called whenever the `IsEnabledProperty` is changed. Then in  this handler, you can set the `IsEnabled` property of all child items to `true` when ever the `Canvas` is disabled. Take a look at [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b965297b-abca-4c8f-a074-a6b46b7abdec/tabitem-isenabled-false-will-not-disable-all-child-controls) that has a similar example but for a `TabItem` control instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I needed to set ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode = ManipulationMode.Control at my page constructor and do not set HorisontalScrollBarVisibility and VerticalScrollVarVisibility (it resets offsets to 0,0 coordinates)
 Now it works.

Thanks!